# VBA Move one cell right and put current date each time macro is run

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code that when, each week, the macro is run will put the date into the range B5:J5 for 9 weeks. My current code is adding the date I want, to the right, I just cannot figure out how to make it keep moving 1 cell right each time the macro is run. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
Sub addDate()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Worksheets("Project LOE").Range("B5:J5")

    For Each cell In r.Cells
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
        End If
        r.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
    Next
End Sub
```

** EDIT

Column B5 has yesterdays date, when I run macro I want it to add today (date macro is ran) into the next cell, C5 then D5 and so on. I don't really have "sample" data as the fields are blank, below is what I am expecting as far as the dates go

```
                 B5         C5         D5               E5
               4/6/2015   4/7/2015  "next run date"   "next run date"
```

F5 Automation
SLA
Runbook
Security Runbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is static

```
Set r = Worksheets("Project LOE").Range("B5:J5")
```

So you need to make it dynamic like:

```
With Worksheets("Project LOE")
    Dim lc As Long
    lc = .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Set r = .Cells(5, lc).Resize(, 9)
End With
```

**Edit1:** It seems you only need this if I understand what you're trying to do correctly.

```
With Worksheets("Project LOE")
    .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = Date
End With
```

Take note that it will always start populating dates on `B5`.

Comment: Thanks - when I replace the static range with your dynamic range, nothing happens. I left my if statement in place, does that need modified as well?

Comment: @DanielStrong It runs fine at my end. Do you have a sample data? Can you edit your question and put it there. Also your expected result.

Comment: edited to show expected outcome. No real sample data as the fields are currently blank. I am leaving the IF statements in my code, i can get it to where it adds the row all the way across, but not one by one as I need.